# Pass tv value to placeholder using getImageList snippet

Tags: modx-revolution

for example chunk img `<img src="[[+src]]">[[+image]]</img>`
then when i call chunk i can pass TV values like this `[[$img? &src=[[*myTVProperty_1]] &image=[[*myTVProperty_2]]]]` so my TV property name not suppose to match my placeholders name

But when i use MIGX getImageList it seems i can't pass my TV like that

```
[[!getImageList? &tvname=`myTV` &docid=`1` &tpl=`image` &src=[[*myTVProperty_1]] &image=[[*myTVProperty_2]]]]
```

It doesn't work until i make my tv properties to match placeholders names.
It is inconvenient since i might want to make my chunk work with regular tvs and migx snipper and have freedom to name my tvs whatever i like.
Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question clearly, but I can tell you, '&src' '&image' are not getImageList snippet properties. I think you need to work with your &src and &image inside your image chunk.

https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/migx/migx.frontend-usage

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any values in any names, just remember that to read them you must add **+property**, for example:

MIGX Items:

```
[[!getImageList? &tvname=`myTV` &docid=`1` &tpl=`tpl_image` &src=`[[*myTVProperty_1]]` &alt=`[[*myTVProperty_2]]]]`
```

Template **tpl_image**:

```
<img src="[[+property.src]]" alt="[[+property.alt]]">
```